viopenDefaultRm failed to initialize
#include <stdio.h>
#include <visa.h>

int main (void)
{
        ViStatus status = VI_SUCCESS;
        
        ViUInt32 returnCount = 0;
        ViSession rmHandle, scopeHandle;
        char responseBuffer[1024];
        char resourceString[] = "TCPIP::192.168.10.171::INSTR";
        status = viOpenDefaultRM(&rmHandle);
  
        if (status < VI_SUCCESS) {
        printf("Failed to open Resource manager. Error code: %d\n", status);
        return -1; 
    } else {
    printf("Resource manager opened successfully.\n");
}

I want to remote control a device with c code. Code is working properly. No warnings no errors. unfortunately, viopenDefaultRm function doesnt initialize. i added visa64.lib file by the way. how can i fix this, first of all this function must be initialize. then i will sent scpi commands.
why viopenDefaultRm function doesnt work?
